# Update a single variable in my entire collection in Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update a variable after click the button.
This is my collection in firestore, and this is my variable what i want to update.
[Firestore Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGI28.png)

That variable "bagAmount", after click I want all of them to be equal to 1.
I know how update one of then, past the ID of my document, like that:

```
this.firestore.doc("lunch/" + this.bagIndex).update({bagAmount: 1});
```

But how i update all?
Thanks!

Comment: You have to query for all the documents, iterate the results, and update each document individually.  There is no equivalent of a SQL "UPDATE WHERE" statement that updates multiple documents at once.

Answer (score 0):

Several methods exist for writing data to Cloud Firestore:

- By specifically mentioning a document identifier, set the data for the document within a collection. Add a fresh document to a repository.
- In this instance, the document identifier is generated automatically by Cloud Firestore.
- Create a blank document with a randomly generated identification, then fill it with information afterward.